# Run subprocess at high prio

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I need to run a jar file from my python script that has to meet some realtime requirements (it's a programmer).

What I currently do is

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("java programmer.jar"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but the programmer stalls on a regular basis what doesn't happen if I start it by hand using `start /high java programmer.jar`. So I'd like to somehow also set the priority of the subprocess directly from my python script.
But if use the command above, I get a `FileNotFoundError`, so Google told me that I have to use the `shell=True` flag. That solved my problem but created a new one as I now have my jar running in another shell so I cannot parse the `stdout` anymore what I have to do to take some actions.

So is there a way to either run `subprocess` directly at a higher priority or to redirect the console output of the shell it creates when I run

```
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("java programmer.jar"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

This has to run on Windows

Comment: 3.7+ defines [`subprocess.HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS) for use with the `creationflags` parameter. In older versions you can define the constant manually: `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000080`.

Comment: FYI, a console window is not a shell. If you're getting a new console, it's from using CMD's `start` command without the `/b` argument. This has CMD call `CreateProcessW` with the flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, which tells the child java.exe process (i.e. startup code in kernelbase.dll in the java.exe process) to allocate a new console. Since CMD doesn't use the `STARTUPINFO` standard handles when creating the process, the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag also has java.exe replace its stdout with the console screen-buffer handle.

Comment: That helped thanks, do you wanna create an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel schedules a thread at one of 32 [priority levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/scheduling-priorities). The base priority depends on the thread priority relative to the process priority class:

```
IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000040
BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00004000
NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000020
ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00008000
HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000080
REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000100
```

The realtime-priority class should only be used when absolutely necessary and only for short-lived operations. Even the high-priority class should be used sparingly and with care.

The initial priority class of a process can be set via the `dwCreationFlags` parameter of [`CreateProcessW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw). Python's [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) supports this as its `creationflags` parameter. For convenience, the above priority-class constants were [added in 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#windows-constants), but of course we can use these flag values in previous versions of Python.